# To create a program that will add user input letters to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to write a Python program that creates empty dictionary of alphabetic letters. The dictionary must be populated such that when a user enters any letter, it will be appended to the dictionary as a key (capital case) and value (small case). All letters of the dictionary must be unique, which means no duplicates are allowed in the dictionary.
For example:

```
Enter any letters (separated with space): A b C d a
{'A': 'a','B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd'}
```

So, here's my code:

```
letter_dictionary = {}
letters = input().split(' ')
for i in letters:
    if i.upper() not in letter_dictionary:
        letter_dictionary[i.upper] = i.lower

print(letter_dictionary)
```

But the problem is, that the program adds to dictionary not letters, but functions lower() and upper(), as I saw on pythontutor.com 
What can I do with it?

Comment: You are missing the parentheses of the `upper` and `lower` functions when adding to the dictionary

Comment: Damn, i should be more careful. Thank you, man!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> letter_dictionary[i.upper()] = i.lower()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `str.upper` and `str.lower` are [method objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects), you need to follow them with parentheses to actually apply the methods:

```
for i in letters:
    if i.upper() not in letter_dictionary:
        letter_dictionary[i.upper()] = i.lower()
```

But a regular `for` loop isn't required here. Even the `not in letter_dictionary` check isn't strictly necessary, since dictionary keys are *always* unique. If you want to apply a uniqueness check, just use `set` on your input first.

So you can rewrite using a dictionary comprehension:

```
letter_diction = {k.upper(): k.lower() for k in set(letters)}
```